# How do I get the OpenSSO/OpenAM Fedlet working w/ ADFS 2.0?

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0, opensso

I'm trying to get the OpenSSO(OpenAM) fedlet up and running against an ADFS2.0 server. I've gotten imported their metadata (idp.xml) and exchanged certificates with the ADFS server. I had to remove some elements from the XML file; claimstypes and some other such elements.

When I click the "Run Fedlet (SP) initiated Single Sign-On using HTTP POST binding" link to attempt a SSO, I get bounced to an "HTTP Status 500 - Single Sign On failed" page.

My fedlet is running on myServer.domain.net and the ADFS server is adfs.domain.net.

I've decoded the SAML request that I'm making to the ADFS server:

```
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" ID="s25420b00d06164c30c915b9f69c6e5b73408c6b27" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2011-03-14T21:37:27Z" Destination="https://adfs.domain.net/adfs/ls/" ForceAuthn="false" IsPassive="false" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://myServer:8999/fedlet/fedletapplication">
    <saml:Issuer xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">myServer.domain.net</saml:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient" SPNameQualifier="myServer.domain.net" AllowCreate="true"></samlp:NameIDPolicy>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

These are the errors and stack stack trace from my jboss log:

```
2011-03-14 16:22:00,330 ERROR [STDERR] Mar 14, 2011 4:22:00 PM com.sun.identity.plugin.log.impl.FedletLogger access
INFO: GOT_RESPONSE_FROM_POST
{}
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR] Mar 14, 2011 4:22:00 PM com.sun.identity.plugin.log.impl.FedletLogger error
INFO: WRONG_STATUS_CODE
{_12549e97-9ef2-49f2-a3c2-3dd40171ce8a}
{}
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 INFO  [STDOUT] ### {SAMLResponse=[Ljava.lang.String;@1d341d34}\
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 INFO  [STDOUT] ### SAMLResponse:
```

The SAMLResponse from the ADFS server:

```
<samlp:Response ID="_12549e97-9ef2-49f2-a3c2-3dd40171ce8a" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2011-03-14T21:22:38.770Z" Destination="https://myServer:8999/fedlet/fedletapplication" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="s2d4265ae10edc2e33c08dc34c248a95dd771ce4ce" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://adfs.domain.net/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
  <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo>
      <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
      <ds:Reference URI="#_12549e97-9ef2-49f2-a3c2-3dd40171ce8a">
        <ds:Transforms>
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
          <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </ds:Transforms>
        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
        <ds:DigestValue>AX/P9yGMxS6g8X5wbWqV1bbDeIxJXuHhr5OK3VJ9lzU=</ds:DigestValue>
      </ds:Reference>
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:SignatureValue>ViPPkKk8KLx6TUHWjaVcbiDHEBQOio7+7gJqC2lnVeT6Ja4MqrF6GtIX8MjwHAHM+s5gOcxdldPYoKNfAkh12C690BQvlWXQd0nc6NmDVNvYGSCWy2JL19wiBDoNreWO4YwCXOoeHOS/CvsxB1gE5CiyQ8BzbsIAGvH3+uIVOcOrj30SuDQkXYBqnZw5OPM9BlmG7C4UBS8wlO44Ukbvs0oqwgVxSeBk6kywBYW9PoNGCc6ViTZwhWoQYGj2dFd/k282mzaZ4cz+aHBpAYMju9QJuXPpzdtP4Ms6x8BxpBrQUwPcg9+wV+jtwCmMgarFfOWwlR00b6m64XdPK9bmJw==</ds:SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <ds:X509Data>
        <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
      </ds:X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </ds:Signature>
  <samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Responder" />
  </samlp:Status>
</samlp:Response>
```

The error/stacktrace:

```
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR] com.sun.identity.saml2.common.SAML2Exception: Single Sign On failed.
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.sun.identity.saml2.profile.SPACSUtils.processResponseForFedlet(Unknown Source)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.jsp.fedletSampleApp_jsp._jspService(fedletSampleApp_jsp.java:262)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:97)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:332)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,331 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:810)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:392)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
2011-03-14 16:22:00,332 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:810)
```

Could this be from editing the metadata that the ADFS server provided me? I'm having trouble figuring out where to dig from here.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read through [Creating a Virtual Organization Using Federated Identity Services with OpenSSO and Microsoft Active Directory Federation Services](http://www.interopvendoralliance.org/labs/v-org-using-federated-identity-services-with-with-ad-fs-2-and--sun-sso.aspx)?.

The details are in the White Paper at the bottom.

The OpenSSO instructions are here : [WS-Federation Operations](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19681-01/820-3885/ghuot/index.html)

Comment: In my case there was a duplicate nameID coming across from the IDP. I wish I had found these links sooner though. I wish I had this stuff last week when I started to set things up.

Comment: @aCodeMonkey: I realize it's a long time ago, but do you perhaps remember how you had 'a duplicate nameID' from AD FS 2.0?  Did you emit two nameID claims?  (Background.  We're seeing the same problem, in a more complicated scenario, and we're having a hard time figuring out what is wrong in our configuration...)